# Can I store a set of strings of a multiple line using regex on java?

Tags: java, regex

If I have an input of

```
this is a string
this is also a string
i am a string
```

can i store them in an array like

```
[0] this is a string
[1] this is also a string
[2] i am a string
```

If so, how can I achieve this kind of output?

Comment: `String[] array = input.split("\n");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: How are you getting your input?

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
String[] output = input.split"\\r?\\n");
```

That would split the lines if \r\n or \n is used for line breaks.